# POSIX threads and keys

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

I need to create two private keys and two threads and then I need to make these threads "exchange" keys
I already created the keys and initialized them and I can also print their value, but I do not know how to make them exchange keys. Maybe someone will tell you something. maybe for this I need to call the same thread several times, but I also don’t know how to do this. I do not ask you to give me a ready-made program, maybe just some little hint or advice

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_key_t key, key2;

void get_data()
{
    int *x = (int*)pthread_getspecific(key2);
    if(x == NULL)
        printf("The value is NULL\n");
    else
        printf("Key value is %d\n", *x);
}

void get_data2()
{
        int *x = (int*)pthread_getspecific(key);
        if(x == NULL)
                printf("The value is NULL\n");
        else
                printf("Key value is %d\n", *x);
}


void *func(void *data)
{
    int *num;
    int *x;
    printf("Thread №%ld\n", pthread_self());
    num = (int*)data;
    get_data();
    pthread_setspecific(key, (void*)num);
    get_data();
}

void *func2(void *data)
{
    int *num;
        int *x;
        printf("Thread №%ld\n", pthread_self());
        num = (int*)data;
        get_data2();
        pthread_setspecific(key2, (void*)num);
        get_data2();

}



int main()
{
    int ret_code, type = 3;
    pthread_t th, th2;

    ret_code = pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);
    if(ret_code != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "ptrhead_key_create() error %d\n", ret_code);

    ret_code = pthread_key_create(&key2, NULL);
        if(ret_code != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "ptrhead_key_create() error %d\n", ret_code);


    printf("type: %d\n", type);
    ret_code = pthread_create(&th, NULL, func, (void*)&type);
    if(ret_code != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create() error %d\n", ret_code);

    sleep(1);
    type = 10;

    printf("type: %d\n", type);
        ret_code = pthread_create(&th2, NULL, func2, (void*)&type);
        if(ret_code != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create() error %d\n", ret_code);



    ret_code = pthread_join(th, NULL);
    ret_code = pthread_join(th2, NULL);


}
```

Comment: Can you describe *why* they need to exchange keys?  I understand keys are used for thread local storage and it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: There is no need to *exchange* your `key` and `key2` between threads, as both keys are already accessible to both threads.  They are keys for accessing *thread-local storage*, so (1) you don't need different keys for different threads, because (2) each thread always and only gets *its own* data via any given key.

Comment: If you want to exchange the data associated with the key(s) then each thread needs to put its data somewhere where the other can access it.  Regular file-scope variables could serve for that purpose, or you could use pipes.  There are other alternatives.  If you use memory then you need to be careful to properly synchronize, such as via semaphores or condition variables.

Comment: None of the eight casts in the code seem necessary. Are you sure you're using a C compiler?

Comment: When I see the word "exchange" in a threading context, I think they're looking for an atomic operation to achieve this, but I'm still not sure what they're trying to accomplish.